# StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING not dispatched

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, mobile, air

I'm testing my starling application on iPhone 4, I suspect this is happening because of the obsolete IOS version.

```
package
{

    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.StageOrientationEvent;
    import flash.display.Sprite;

    public class Startup extends Sprite
    {

        public function Startup():void
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
        }

        private function onAddedToStage(e:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

            stage.addEventListener(StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING, orientationChangeListener);
        }

        private function orientationChangeListener(e:StageOrientationEvent):void
        {
            Debug.write("orientation: " + stage.orientation); //Never called
        }

    }

}
```

application.xml has autoOrients set to "true" and aspectRatio set to "landscape", I also tried deleting aspectRatio as suggested in some stackoverflow answer, to no avail.

StageOrientationEvent.ORIENTATION_CHANGING is never dispatched in my application.

Another weird thing is happening, which might help you understand the situation better:

Even though aspectRatio is set to "landscape" in application.xml, the app opens in portrait mode, and stage.orientation returns "rotatedRight" (meaning landscape).
I can only set to landscape properly by setting aspectRatio to "portrait" in application.xml, and then manually setting to "landscape" in runtime:

```
stage.setOrientation(StageOrientation.ROTATED_RIGHT);
```

Comment: what's your AIR SDK version ? I've experienced a lot of problems two years ago with orientation when developing a universal phone/tablet app, with a vertical layout on phone, horizontal on tablet. Since then, I haven't messed anymore with dynamic orientation, and sticked with static orientation defined in application descripto, but I've seen several times bugfixes about orientation in various AIR SDK release notes

Comment: AIR 18.0. I want to lock the orientation to landscape only (which still changes between rotatedRight and rotatedLeft), but simply specifying that in application.xml doesn't do the trick, so I'm resorting to manually detecting the orientation change.

Comment: Since there was a mistake in the posted code I need to delete my answer now.

Comment: un deleted my answer and changed its contents.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to lock landscape mode then first in description XML set aspectRatio  to landscape and autoOrient to true then in code do:

```
stage.setAspectRatio(StageAspectRatio.LANDSCAPE);
stage.autoOrients = true;
```

And the device will not go through portrait.

Comment: Similarly to the case I specified in my post, for some reason it doesn't work. The app is opened in portrait and stage.orientation returns "rotatedRight".

Comment: Instead of keep trying to make it work with your whole project just put a simple empty app together and try with that. Since Starling is well known to be extremely intrusive it's very likely it's Starling that is causing that mess.

Comment: You can see from a quick search in starling's source that it doesn't deal with orientation at all. Regardless, I created a clean project for testing, with nothing but this code - I got the exact same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
    <aspectRatio>landscape</aspectRatio>
```

should be the way to gay, it has always worked for us but we dont have published apps using this setting with air sdk 18

since it seems that it doesnt work for you, you may try the dynamic way as a workaround, like we use in our universal build (detects device iphone/ipad in preloader frame, applies correct orientation, instantiates the right main class), tested on old devices/os versions

with

```
    <autoOrients>true</autoOrients>
    <aspectRatio>any</aspectRatio>
```

and call `stage.setAspectRatio(StageAspectRatio.LANDSCAPE);` asap, meaning right in you main or preloader class constructor

Comment: It's similar to the solution I mentioned at the end of my question. It sets successfully to landscape rotatedRight, but it doesn't switch between rotatedRight and rotatedLeft when I rotate my device, it's stuck on a fixed rotatedRight. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: I'd like to mention that other apps rotate well on my device.